# TopMost не работает в Windows CE 6.0 (Micros Workstation 5.0)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-ce

Создаю приложения для терминала Micros Workstation 5 (Windows CE 6.0). Моё приложение должно всегда находится поверх остальных, для чего я применил к форме свойство TopMost. Оно перекрывает все открытые приложения, но всё равно остаётся ниже, чем одно из встроенных приложений на терминале. Есть какой-то другой способ поднять форму на самый верх?

Comment: Возможно, в том приложении TopMost постоянно обновляется по таймеру (я так когда-то делал). Это действенный способ. Впрочем, за него нужно отрубать руки... (пишу носом)

Comment: Не думаю. Оно запускается в полноэкранном режиме и просто закрывает всё остальное. А мне нужно, чтобы моё приложение всегда было поверх, даже если есть приложения на весь экран.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще простого. Для того, чтобы Ваше приложение всегда перекрывало остальные, необходимо на событие формы Deactivate добавить метод с кодом

```
this.BringToFront();
```

После этого при взаимодействии с другими приложениями, Ваше приложение будет терять фокус, но всегда оставаться поверх остальных.